# What does a dashed / dotted relationship line represent in SQL Management Studio - Database Diagram

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, ssms, database-diagram

I'm looking at an existing database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and in the Database Diagram there is one relatioship that appears with a dashed or dotted line.  The other relationships are all solid lines.  What does the dashed line mean?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dotted/dashed line means, that SQL Server does not enforce referential integrity for this relationship. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188251.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

referential integrity is not enforced