# Entity Relationships: Difference between solid line and dotted line

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

In the use of table relationship. What is  the difference in the use of solid line and dotted line?

For Example

TABLE : MESSAGES /
TABLE : USERS

An User have 0 or Many Messages.

Solid line or Dotted Line?

Comment: Referential integrity.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347917/what-does-a-dashed-dotted-relationship-line-represent-in-sql-management-studio

Comment: In MySQL Workbench EER Diagrams the dotted line indicates a non-identifying relationship, a solid line indicates an identifying relationship : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html

Comment: @PaulF why did you add your answer as comment and not as a normal answer?

Comment: @MikeLischke: I just looked at it as telling the OP to read the documentation which is not something I should get any credit for. I guess I could put it there so it can be marked as answered for future reference.

Comment: Also, the documentation was updated after seeing this SO entry. Hopefully it's a little clearer now.

Comment: Hello PaulF. Do you mind if I add the answer with some example cases?

Answer (score 10):

As stated at the comments, a dotted line indicates  non-identifying relationship.

**SOLID LINE => IDENTIFYING relationship**

> **Definition from mySQL docs:** An identifying relationship is one where the child table cannot be uniquely identified without its parent. Typically this
> occurs where an intermediary table is created to resolve a
> many-to-many relationship. In such cases, the primary key is usually a
> composite key made up of the primary keys from the two original
> tables.

Example:
We have an application that registers the arrival time of the employees with this model:

```
user { id_user, name, department, job } 
arrival_log { id_user, arrival_time, department }
```

Each row of arrival_log requires the user_id to be specified. Without the user_id, we wouldn't know who reached the offices. The entity arrival_log is a weak one because it depends on other entities' existence (user) to work.

**DOTTED LINE => NON-IDENTIFYING relationship.**

**Definition:** A non-identifying relationship is one where the child can be identified independently of the parent.

Example:

```
flower( flower_id, flower_latin_name, flower_type_id )
flower_type( flower_type_id, name, description )
```

The relationship between flower and flower_type is non-identifying because each flower_type can be identified without having to exist in the flower table.